# Is it permissible to hug the wife in the month of Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, sex

I would like to know if it is permissible to hug the wife in the month of Ramadan in bed? What's the ruling if they are fasting?

**Edit / Clarification:**

I suspect sexual intercourse isn't allowed **when any spouse is fasting** (correct me if I am wrong), so my questions are:

- Is intercourse allowed in the month of Ramadan when both spouses don't have fast?
- If any **one** of the spouses has fast, can they still hug each other but do not have intercourse?

Answer (score 9):

The answer lies in the Qur'an:

[image]

> **Translation:** It has been made permissible for you the night preceding fasting to go to your wives [for sexual relations]. They are
>   clothing for you and you are clothing for them. Allah knows that you
>   used to deceive yourselves, so He accepted your repentance and forgave
>   you. So now, have relations with them and seek that which Allah has
>   decreed for you. [...] ([Surah Baqarah, verse 187](http://quran.com/2/187))

Based on this ayah, scholars have said that it's permissible for couples to have physical relations during the nights of Ramadan (which I believe is what you're asking about). Although the translation here says "the night preceding fasting," it talks about during Ramadan.

Also, It's worth noting that fasting prohibits only the actual act of intercourse. Aisha narrated that:

> **The Prophet would kiss during the month of fasting.** ([Jaami at-Tirmidhi, grade: Sahih](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/4#46))

Wallahu a'lam.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see updated question for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Fasts are supposed to help us learn self restraint in atleast 3 desires.

1) Hunger

2) Thirst

3) Sexual

> O ye who believe! Fasting is prescribed to you as it was prescribed to those before you, that ye may (learn) self-restraint,- ([2:183](http://quran.com/2/183))

When we fast we do not indulge in any activity that would in anyway ignite or satisfy these desires.

**Between iftar and suhur we can eat, drink and have sex (but no sex in itikaf).**

> **Permitted to you, on the night of the fasts, is the approach to your wives.** They are your garments and ye are their garments. Allah knoweth what ye used to do secretly among yourselves; but He turned to you and forgave you; so now associate with them, and seek what Allah Hath ordained for you, and **eat and drink, until the white thread of dawn appear to you distinct from its black thread; then complete your fast Till the night appears;** but **do not associate with your wives while ye are in retreat in the mosques**. Those are Limits (set by) Allah: Approach not nigh thereto. Thus doth Allah make clear His Signs to men: that they may learn self-restraint.([2:187](http://quran.com/2/187))

**About Hugging**

If a couple is newly married, even a phone call might ignite sexual desires BUT if a couple is old, much physical contact might not ignite anything. It depends from couple to couple. The couple should talk and set boundaries during fast.

The idea here is not "if hugging is permitted" rather it is "if hugging ignites sexual desires to nullify the fast"

Sometimes the effect of certain gestures (like hugging) might not be known to the couple, so I advise not to involve in them so as to keep the fast intact.

Comment: -1 for 1) translating the first ayah (2:183) wrongly, the last words are not likely to be translated as self-restraint, you should have chosen a correct translation, perhaps Yusuf Ali missed in this ayah, 2) The about hugging section is ambiguous, it doesn't provide any kind of reference/citation .

Comment: +1 the answer addressed the question properly. 1) [2:183](http://www.cmje.org/religious-texts/quran/verses/002-qmt.php) translation is correct by Yousaf Ali. It was not modifed. You cannot downvote based on that. 2)Hugging part was well addressed conceptually. Of course we do not have a clear verdict on this. But the answer address the issue very logically.

Comment: Many people cite hadees that the Prophet(pbuh) used to kiss his wives, but there many types of kissing, so much so that there are books on the art of kissing. Hence I use the quranic verse that deems "sexual activity" as not permissible in fast and deduce that if a kiss raises sexual feelings then its not permitted in fast. My apologies for mis-translation bit, I will correct that part soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see updated question for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Adding to what others have said:**

Some scholars made it impressible for those who can't control their sexual desires from kissing their wives during Ramadan. Since kissing might lead to sexual intercourse thus losing his/her fast.

It might be worth noting that the prophet (PBUH) **kissed** Aisha while he was fasting. So for those who can control themselves, they are allowed to kiss their wives:

> 'A'isha (Allah be pleased with her) reported:
>   The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to kiss (his wives) while fasting; and he had the greatest control over his desire (as compared with you). [[Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/13/83) and Bukhari]

---

**In conclusion:** *If hugging won't make you reach climax or lead to sexual intercourse then no harm at all.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes I ask one of my imam he said it's totally allowed to do in the night between 12 to before morning like starting fasting

Comment: Welcome to islam se. Please read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to evaluate your answer