# Is there any rule that husband and wife should control themselves having sex or kisses in the month of Ramadaan.

Tags: ramadan, reference-request

Assalam Va Allaikum

Can husband and wife may continue to carry their love even during the month of Ramazaan?
During Ramazaan, are they supposed to keep a little distance?

Can I please have any reference?

Comment: @downvoter : why the downvote ??

Comment: making haram halal and halal haram is sin. wife and husband are mehram  on each other .why you are making them na-mehram when our beloved prophet did not done so?

Comment: i am not making it haram or halal , but I am asking Is there any rule that husband wife should control having sex or kisses in the month of Ramadaan .

Comment: ok, i have edited your question to make it clear

Comment: As long as they don't do anything to invalidate their *siyam* during the morning hours, then surely they are free to do as they will?

Comment: why so many down votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allah Says in the Holy Quran Chapter 2 Surah Baqarah verse 187:

> Permitted to you on the night of the fasts is the approach to your
>   wives.  They are your garments.  And ye are their garments.  Allah
>   knoweth what ye used to do secretly among yourselves; but He turned to
>   you and forgave you; so now associate with them and seek what Allah
>   hath ordained for you and eat and drink until the white thread of dawn
>   appear to you distinct from its black thread; then complete your fast
>   till the night appears; but do not associate with your wives while ye
>   are in retreat in the mosques.  Those are limits (set by) Allah;
>   approach not nigh thereto.  Thus doth Allah make clear His signs to
>   men that they may learn self-restraint.

It is absolutely lawful and permissible in Islam for the husband and the wife to enjoy sex relations with each other during the nights or non-fasting hours of the blessed month of Ramadan.

[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/hugging-wife-in-month-of-ramadan) is also relevant to your question IMHO.

If, Allah forbid, one has sex with one’s wife during the fasting hours in Ramadan see the following Hadith:

> Abu Hurairah reported that a man came to the Messenger of Allah (saws)
>   and said: "I am destroyed, O Messenger of Allah (saws)!" The Prophet
>   (saws) asked: "What has destroyed you?"  He said, "I had intercourse
>   with my wife during a day of Ramadan."  The Prophet (saws) asked: "Are
>   you able to free a slave?"  He said, "No". The Prophet (saws) asked:
>   "Is it possible for you to fast for two consecutive months?" He said,
>   "No." The Prophet (saws) asked: "Is it possible for you to feed sixty
>   poor people?" He said, "No."  The Prophet (saws) said: "Then sit."  A
>   basket of dates was brought to the Prophet (saws) and he said to the
>   man: ‘Give this in charity.’ The man said: "To someone poorer than us?
>   There is no one in this city who is poorer than us!"  The Prophet
>   (saws) laughed until his molar teeth could be seen and said: "Go and
>   feed your family with it!"

Related by the Muslim and Bukhari.

Comment: can you please conclude second hadith

Comment: @user1379280 I don't understand - what do you mean by "conclude second hadith" ?

Comment: i meant , can you please elaborate the second hadith

Comment: @user1379280 the hadith shows basically that sex during fasting is haram and that a "kaffara" is necessary in case one violates that rule

Comment: @user1379280 Sex, eating, drinking, smoking are all forbidden during the month of Ramadan. I advise you get a good Islamic book on "fasting" before Ramadan comes.